# How does this acquire-release relationship work?

Tags: multithreading, rust, atomic, memory-barriers

In [Rust Atomics and Locks](https://marabos.nl/atomics/), more or less the following code is suggested for appropriately implementing the `drop` trait of a simplified `Arc`: (code is mine)

```rust
        unsafe {
            if 1 == (*self.inner).strong.fetch_sub(1, Release) {
                fence(Acquire);
                let box_ = Box::rom_raw(self.inner);
                drop(box_);
            }
        }
```

where `(*self.inner).strong` is an `AtomicUsize`.

So here is my question:

I understand that an `acquire` will establish a "happens-before/synchronize-with" relationship with the previous `release` (with the thread where the loaded value was written). In order to properly `drop` the value, we need each `Arc` to have their `fetch_sub` linked one after the other.

I don't understand how this is guaranteed here. I would understand if we `acquired` the atomic's value, subbed one, and then `release`d, all in a single operation (basically `fetch_sub` with `AcqRel` ordering or a compare and swap loop).

Here, we only "acquire" when we load 1. My understanding of using `Release` on `fetch_sub` is that the `fetch` part is `relaxed`. Based on this understanding, I have two issues with the aforementioned code:

#### 1

Wouldn't this case be possible:

```
Thread A:
  load: 2 (t = 1)
  write 1 (t = ?)
Thread B:
  load: 2 (t = 1)
  write 1 (t = ?)
```

and thus the value was never dropped? I fail to see how the `load` has a guarantee that it has exclusive access over the value, implying it will always load in order.

#### 2

Am I not establishing only a "happens-before" relationship between the reading of `1` and the drop? I think this is fine, since I can **only** drop if I indeed see a `1`, but how am I guaranteed to see that `1` and not have a data race on the atomic?

I suspect my misunderstanding comes from the guarantees provided by atomics/ordering, but

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Atomic read-modify-write instructions are always atomic, regardless of the memory ordering chosen.  So if let's say `self.inner` has the value 5, and then you do `fetch_sub(1, Relaxed)` in any combination of different threads, you are still guaranteed that exactly one of them will load the value 2 and store the value 1.

Rust doesn't have a formally defined memory model, but AFAIK in practice it follows C++, which specifies this behavior by saying that "an atomic read-modify-write always loads the value that, in the modification order of the object, immediately precedes the value it stored."  https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/atomics.order#10

You do have a happens-before relationship between the load of 1 and the drop, but that is trivial; for operations within a single thread, happens-before always follows program order.  Confusingly, this does not mean that they cannot be reordered for execution!

What you really care about is that *all prior accesses* to `box_`, from other threads, must happen-before the drop.  That's the condition that avoids a data race.  And this you do get, thanks to the use of acquire and release ordering.

It would be a little simpler to see why if the `fetch_sub` used `AcqRel` ordering.  In that case, we would have:

- the last prior access happens-before the store of the value 1 (because it precedes that `fetch_sub` in program order within a single thread)
- the store of 1 synchronizes with the load of 1, because the former is release, the latter is acquire, and the value observed by the load was the value put there by the store
- the load of 1 happens-before the drop (program order)
- happens-before is transitive.

You can argue similarly for all other accesses to the box.

But using `AcqRel` is somewhat inefficient, because we are paying for acquire ordering on every `fetch_sub`, but we really only need it for the last one (the one which loads the value 1).  So in this code, we instead use `Release` ordering only on the `fetch_sub`, together with an `Acquire` fence which is only executed conditionally when the value loaded equals 1.  The fence can be thought of as "retroactively" promoting the relaxed load of the `fetch_sub` to acquire.  The formal proof takes a little more work, but it all does work out.

There's another side question: with `Release` ordering only, you no longer have a full happens-before chain involving all the `fetch_subs`, so how do you guarantee that the `drop` happens-after the second-to-last access?  The C++ memory model handles this with the concept of a "release sequence".  Normally, a load can only synchronize with a store if it loads the value put there by the store.  But release sequences mean it also "counts" if you load a value that was produced by some sequence of atomic read-modify-writes acting on the value originally stored.  So your drop not only happens-after the store of the value 1, it also happens-after a hypothetical store of the value 47 (since we could only have reached 1 via some long chain of atomic `fetch_add` and `fetch_sub`).

Comment: Thanks for the link, it made me go down a rabbit hole; I think I understand a little more now:
- load/store prevents data races / torn read/writes
- rmw also prevents race conditions

which means my first point is impossible because of the rmw used (basically a cache sync is forced?). 

I'm still unsure how the `release/acquire` fits in all of this, since `rmw` order basically ensures the right order and the `box_` drop is wrapped in an `if`, does this code need to use ordering at all?

Comment: @SamuelYvon: RMW speaks about how the accesses to `inner` occur relative to one another, and says nothing about ordering relative to the accesses to `box_`.  You might think the `if` (control dependency) enforces ordering but it does not.  For instance, maybe the `drop` reads some data structures that were previously changing; without the fence, those reads could be hoisted out of the `if` and done *unconditionally* before the `fetch_sub`, with the results simply being discarded if the `fetch_sub` returns greater than 1.

Comment: @SamuelYvon: One can even imagine ways that *writes* which should only be done conditionally could become visible before the load that triggered them.  For instance, the machine could do the `drop` first, then the `fetch_sub`, and have some way to "roll back" the entire process if the value returned was greater than 1.  I don't think any real-life implementation can actually do it, but the memory model allows it if the acquire ordering is not there.

Comment: It is still a bit fuzzy, but I can see re-ordering before `if` being a problem for unrelated data (for instance if the `drop` code is being inlined). Basically the `release/acquire` keeps the ordering visible to me, the programmer as the real ordering, and the atomics keeps their own ordering through the `rmw` order. Both of these (combined) ensures the behavior I'm expecting. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Atomic operations are always fully atomic (i.e. as if they were `acquire-release`) for the atomic data. The ordering parameter only relates to operations on *other* data. So `release` only means that memory writes to *other locations* that happened before the operation are visible from other threads, and similarly `acquire` means that memory reads from *other locations* after the operation will see everything that was committed by other threads at the time of the operation.

Comment: I think it's misleading to use "acquire-release" in conjunction with "fully atomic".  Acquire/release is entirely about how this access is ordered with accesses to *other* objects, whereas the atomicity is about accesses to this object itself.

Comment: @NateEldredge better like this?

Comment: I would not mention acquire/release at all in this context.

Comment: I only mention it because the OP does in the question. I believe the rest of the answer makes it clear that the ordering parameter doesn't apply to the atomic data itself.

Comment: It's just plain wrong to say "i.e." to connect "fully atomic" to `acquire-release`.  An atomic RMW with `memory_order_relaxed` is still indivisible (no other operation *on that object* can happen during it), but both its load and store parts can still reorder with other operations from this thread on other variables in ways that `acq_rel` wouldn't allow.

Comment: Oh, I should have kept reading, I see you're making the distinction of not reordering with other accesses to the same object.  Perhaps put the parenthetical aside after the whole sentence, so the scope limit comes first in the reader's mind.  If you want to put it that way, it's `seq_cst` not `acq_rel`: the store from one RMW can't reorder with the load side of the next RMW on the same location.  To get linearizability (e.g. no lost counts), atomic RMWs always see the "latest value" in the modification order.